# Runtime of UWP app

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, clr

I can't find any deep information about how UWP apps are actually running.
I read on Wikipedia that UWP is based on WinRT. WinRT incorporates some kind of .NET runtime. Is it CLR? Is it some form of CLR or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UWP has nothing to do with .NET or the CLR. It is implemented in C++ and uses COM under the hood. It is *language agnostic*, meaning its API can be consumed by different languages (C#, VB.NET, F#, C++/CX, C++ and JavaScript right now).

If you're using C# to consume the UWP APIs, then the UWP types are projected into equivalent CLR types. For example, if you instantiate a `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` instance, not only do you get a CLR `System.Object` back, but under the hood the underlying COM object is "activated" a-la [RoActivateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br224646(v=vs.85).aspx) (or something like that).

Comment: Wow, it shed some light, thank you. Don't you know where can I read about UWP internals in more depth?